# How I can add color swatches in quick view page in Shopify?

Tags: themes, shopify

please check my code from below link
https://www.huratips.com/tech-tips/how-to-create-a-simple-quick-view-without-app-usage-to-your-shopify-store.html

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking how do you display the quickview, i believe you are using a
script for this. If you could post your code here so we can check.

Comment: @Noop Send me  swatches quick view code if you have , because i dont have any idea how to creae swatches in quick view page .

Comment: I actually can't send you a code since i am not sure how do you display it, but simple displaying of swatches is something you could do by displaying the product variants using this tutorial: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product_option